# How do I change the terminal command type in VSCode

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

Im running VSCode on Mac and I'm trying to write a Ruby script, however everytime I try to run the file I get this error:

```
/Ruby/test.rb: line 1: puts: command not found
```

I notice that the terminal is set up to use bash. I suspect that I need to somehow configure the terminal to recognize the script as Ruby, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: How do you run the script? You execute the script like a bash file.
To run a ruby script you have to run it like this:  `ruby test.rb`

Comment: How do i configure that in VSCode? If I run it in a separate terminal using the ruby command it works, but VSCode doesnt add the ruby command automatically in VSCode, even though I have it saved as a .rb file and set up the language as Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add **.** to the start of the file but make sure you do the following before executing it

1. start your program with #!/usr/bin/env ruby,
2. make your file executable by running chmod +x your_program.rb
3. and do **.**/your_program.rb some_param

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!